# Fix specific links in website not working on iphone only

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I'm creating a website from [this](https://www.templatemonster.com/website-templates/yachting-responsive-website-template-61122.html#tab-support) template and I've downloaded the template and uploaded it without modifications [here](http://bmyachts.it/tema_originale/).

I have this problem (confirmed by a ticket on templatemonster): on Iphone only (seems like both on safari and chrome), i cannot click on some links (e.g. "view charateristics" on the 4 boats images under **"YACHTS FOR SALE"**.

I tried editing it:

1. adding a big z-index on the  tags
2. creating a custom section with bootstrap and custom link
3. using `<span>` tags with `onclick="window.location.href='test.php'"`
4. using a `<form>` and a `<button>`

It really seems that the browser does not "catch" the click on the element.

But still, none of them work.

Unluckily, i cannot test on a real phone, but this simulator `https://appetize.io/` seems to work pretty well. I did confirm that the problem is also on real devices, thanks to a customer.

I would like to know if anybody knows to fix this issue, without making the template look much different, thanks

---

**EDIT**

[Here](http://bmyachts.it/new/index2.php)'s the page where i'm trying to fix the bug. As you can see the `<ontouchstart>` is also not working.

I don't know if it would help, but you can also see that the carousel is not working on iphone (not a problem itself, i'm going to hide it).

Answer (score 1):

It's a known Safari Mobile bug, you should add the `ontouchstart` event handler

[More infos here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#Safari_Mobile)

Comment: I'm sorry, i never used it, do i just have to add something like this:  ontouchstart="window.location.href='test.php'"?

Comment: I tried doing that, but it still doesn't work on iphone. It seems it's a different problem. Still, thanks.

Comment: I've added the link to the bugfixing page in the question, could you please see if i've implemented the ontouchstart correctly? Thank you.

Comment: I tried the link you provided on iphone and the links with ontouchstart on iphone are working